# Template class and nested class C++

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes

I have a problem with `typename SnakeGame`. I would like to know how to make `SnakeGame` to global type in class `KeyboardEvents`. Now a nested class like `DirectionKeyboard` don't know what the type `SnakeGame` is, since it only sees see `KeyboardEvents<SnakeGame>` type. I don't know how to change it :P

Here's the error:

no know conversion for argument 1 from 'KeyboardEvents SnakeGame>&' to 'SnakeGame&'

I would really appreciate help .

keyboardEvents.hpp

```
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>

template <typename SnakeGame>
class KeyboardEvents {
public:
    virtual ~KeyboardEvents() = default;

protected:
    class DirectionKeyboardEvent{
    public:
        virtual ~DirectionKeyboardEvent() = default;
        virtual void direction(SnakeGame&) = 0; // error no know conversion 
    };      

    class GoRight : public DirectionKeyboardEvent {
    public:
        void direction(SnakeGame& snakeObj) {
            snakeObj.snake[0].xCoor+=1;
        }
    };

    class GoRight : public DirectionKeyboardEvent {
    public:
        void direction(SnakeGame& snakeObj){
            snakeObj.snake[0].xCoor += 1;
        }
    };

    class GoLeft : public DirectionKeyboardEvent{
    public:
        void direction(SnakeGame& snakeObj){
            snakeObj.snake[0].xCoor-=1;
        }                     
    };                            

    class GoUp:public DirectionKeyboardEvent{
    public:
        void direction(SnakeGame& snakeObj){
            snakeObj.snake[0].yCoor-=1;
        }                   
    };

    class GoDown : public DirectionKeyboardEvent{
    public:
        void direction(SnakeGame& snakeObj){
            snakeObj.snake[0].yCoor+=1;
        }
    };

    std::map<sf::Keyboard::Key,  std::shared_ptr<DirectionKeyboardEvent>> mapOfDirects;

    void initializeDirectionMap() {
        mapOfDirects[sf::Keyboard::Right] = std::shared_ptr< DirectionKeyboardEvent >(new GoRight);
        mapOfDirects[sf::Keyboard::Left] = std::shared_ptr<DirectionKeyboardEvent>(new GoLeft);
        mapOfDirects[sf::Keyboard::Up] = std::shared_ptr<DirectionKeyboardEvent>(new GoUp);
        mapOfDirects[sf::Keyboard::Down] = std::shared_ptr<DirectionKeyboardEvent>(new GoDown);
    }

    void chooseMethodFromKeyboardArrows(sf::Keyboard::Key codeFromKeyboard) {
        auto iterator = mapOfDirects.find(codeFromKeyboard);

        if(iterator!=mapOfDirects.end()){
            iterator->second->direction(*this);//left , right,up , down, pause
            mainDirection=codeFromKeyboard;
        } else {
            mapOfDirects[mainDirection]->direction(*this);
        }
    }
};
```

Here's the class where I use `KeyboardEvents` ~ snakeGame.hpp

```
#include"keyboardEvents.hpp"

class SnakeGame:public Screen, public KeyboardEvents<SnakeGame> {
    public:
        SnakeGame(int size=16, int width=15, int height=15, int timeDelay=60000)
            : Screen(size, width, height), KeyboardEvents<SnakeGame>(), timeDelay(timeDelay) {}
};
```

Comment: you can have an iner member `SnakeGame s` and then check is type.

Comment: `SnakeGame` is a class , and I want change memebers of that class in `KeyboardEvents` class. For this reason `SnakeGame` is template and I pass `SnakeGame` object by reference to directions functions.

Comment: for what purpose do oyu need to know `SnakeGame`'s reall identity?

Comment: I have no other idea :P I had `SnakeGame` and `KeyboardEvents` in one file but i want refactoring this code and I pushed `KeyboardEvents` to `keyboardEvents.hpp` file ;).

Comment: These seems like attempting to overgeneralize your design.  If your KeyboardEvents class is directly poking around in the members of SnakeGame, you won't be able to use any type other than SnakeGame, which makes this a poor use case for templates.

Comment: You are also overusing inheritance.  It makes no sense for a "game" to inherit from a screen object.  The game might contain a screen object

Comment: @Peter I absolutery agree with you but I have no other idea ;/ I have started learning oop and c++ recently and I make silly mistakes. Sorry for that. I am open for criticism and advice :P

Comment: @Klemens btw, you are not forced to put virtual dtors everywhere. Put them in interfaces and abstract class, other superclass might not need it. At least, instead of `virtual ~MyClass(){}` use `virtual ~MyClass() = default`

Comment: Can you post the call site where you invoke the `direction`? If we don't know how you call it, we can't know how to fix the call :P

Comment: Your class SnakeGame inherits from KeyboardEvents, and KeyboardEvents uses SnakeGame, ... Thats a circular dependency and you should avoid it. May be you can move code to SnakeGame class.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot done ;)
@JMA I had `KeyboardEvents` in `SnakeGame` class but program became larger and then I have decited to little refactor this code but i am assuming now it was bad idea :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your try to call the `DirectionKeyboardEvent::direction` inside the `KeyboardEvents` class.

Even if you put a template parameter that happens to be the child class, there is no means to compiler can know in advance that `KeyboardEvents<SnakeGame>` will absolutely be extended by the class `SnakeGame`.

I mean, one could write this code:

```
KeyboardEvents<SnakeGame> keyboardEvents;

keyboardEvents.chooseMethodFromKeyboardArrows(/* some key */);
```

In that case, `keyboardEvents` is not related that much to `SnakeGame`. In fact there is no `SnakeGame` instance created at all! The compiler is right, the function `chooseMethodFromKeyboardArrows` that call `direction` is wrong to assume that a `KeyboardEvents<SnakeGame>` is a `SnakeGame`.

Inheritance work the other way around: a `SnakeGame` is indeed a `KeyboardEvents<SnakeGame>`. The other way is false.

I could show you how *"to make it work"*, but a warning is needed here: you are overusing inheritance, and you used it the wrong way in the case of `KeyboardEvent`. You really should try to rearrange things around, or you'll end up in a real mess.

---

#### The solution "make it work"

Since you are using CRTP, you can tell the compiler that `KeyboardEvents<SnakeGame>` is indeed, in absolutely ALL cases, being extended by `SnakeGame`. If that's really the case, you can just `static_cast` your base class to the child class:

```
if(iterator!=mapOfDirects.end()){
    // Notice the presence of the cast here
    iterator->second->direction(static_cast<SnakeGame&>(*this));
    mainDirection=codeFromKeyboard;
}
```

---

#### The slightly better solution

You can as well using an existing instance of your snake class as parameter.

```
void chooseMethodFromKeyboardArrows(sf::Keyboard::Key codeFromKeyboard, SakeGame& game){
    auto iterator = mapOfDirects.find(codeFromKeyboard);

    if(iterator!=mapOfDirects.end()){
        iterator->second->direction(game);
        mainDirection=codeFromKeyboard;
    } else {
        mapOfDirects[mainDirection]->direction(game);
    }
}
```

---

However, the best idea is to not make `SnakeGame` extending `KeyboardEvent`, but to contain it in the class instead:

```
struct SnakeGame : Screen {
    KeyboardEvent<SnakeGame> event;

    void callEvents() {
        event.chooseMethodFromKeyboardArrows(/* some key */, *this);
    }
};
```

Here's an homework for you:
Try to make the class `KeyboardEvent` not a template. I'm sure you can find a way to pass around your class without the use of themplates, while still accessing directly to your class `SnakeGame`, without casts or interfaces.

Comment: No problem! But please, put some love in your code and format it properly :P

Comment: @Guillaume I love the connection between proper formatting and showing the code some love. I never thought about it that way, lol.

Answer (score 3):

Your design seems a bit overcomplicated. I think the reason this is so is perhaps you were designing it as you went along. Sometimes it helps to sit down and think about these things first, draw boxes and lines on a whiteboard if you have to.

In any case, this isn't a direct answer to your question, it's a suggestion for an alternative based on what I'm *guessing* you are trying to do.

It seems to me that you're trying to implement some generic keyboard input handler and tie it in to your game. It's possible that I'm entirely wrong about this, but if not, consider something like this instead. First, a generic interface for things that receive keyboard events. It need not be a template, this isn't really a good use-case for templates:

```
class KeyboardEventHandler {
public:
    enum Direction { Left, Right, Up, Down };
    virtual ~KeyboardEventHandler () { }
    virtual void onDirectionKey (Direction d) = 0;
};
```

Now your `SnakeGame`, which handles keyboard events, can inherit that and implement its own `SnakeGame`-specific logic:

```
class SnakeGame : public KeyboardEventHandler {
public:
    void onDirectionKey (Direction d) {
        switch (d) {
        case Up: ...
        case Down: ...
        case Left: ...
        case Right: ...
        }
    }
};
```

And then whatever bit of code you have that is actually processing keyboard events and driving all of this can just work with a `KeyboardEventHandler *`, which could be a `SnakeGame`, or could be anything else you decide to use it for in the future.

That's just one possibility for organization. For example, you could structure it like this instead, breaking out the `KeyboardEvent`, which could simplify future additions:

```
class KeyboardEvent {
public:
    enum Direction { Left, Right, Up, Down };
    Direction getDirection () { ... } // or whatever
};

class KeyboardEventHandler {
public:
    virtual ~KeyboardEventHandler () { }
    virtual void onEvent (KeyboardEvent &event) = 0;
};
```

With `SnakeGame` as:

```
class SnakeGame : public KeyboardEventHandler {
public:
    void onEvent (KeyboardEvent &event) {
        ...
    }
};
```

You could name that stuff something else besides `Direction` / `onDirectionKey` if you want, I picked that from your example but just make it something semantically appropriate that is also convenient (e.g. if you plan on expanding it to include more than just the arrows). But whatever, that's beside the point.

There are also 10 zillion other ways to skin this cat but the important take-home point is: *If you're trying to make some generic interface for something, you really can't make it rely on the specific details of what inherits it, otherwise you're defeating the purpose of making it general to begin with.* In that case, either it's not a good case for generic bases / inheritance, or you've just botched the design and need to sit back and rethink.

Remember: Your goal isn't to add as many classes and stuff as possible to your code; you're not going for like, an inheritance high score. Your goal is to keep your code clean, readable, maintainable, correct, possibly reusable, and to make your work easier on yourself. These are tools, don't just use them because you have them, instead use them when you need them to make your life easier.

**However, all that said, this is still overkill for your specific application, although it is an interesting exercise.** To be honest, in your specific case, I'd just chuck all the inheritance and such altogether and do something like:

```
class SnakeGame {
public:
    void handleKeyPress (char c) {
        // ... do the right thing here
    }
}
```

And be done with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I have did `KeyboardEvents` etc. because I have started learning oop and I would training some approaches on snake game. For instance I get rid of `ifs` and `switchs` and I shifted all statemens to classes. When I have `KeyboardEvents` in `SnakeGame` class it was everything ok. But when my program became larger and larger I decided to shift `KeyboardEvents` class to other file and  then I have struggled with this problem. I know this is overkill but I would only practise oop approaches :P But now I know my way to do it is baddish :P

Comment: @Klemens Note that "OOP" does not imply a complete lack of `if` and `switch` statements! OOP concepts are supposed to make design, implementation, and reuse *easier*, not harder, so if you find that things are turning into spaghetti, it's time to sit back and take another look. It often helps to step away from the code for a while and literally do nothing; your mind will usually come up with something good in the background. Also, as an aside, accurately *naming* your objects sometimes helps: At the high level: What is it / what does it do / why does it exist?

Comment: @Klemens (See also [is-a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) and [has-a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a)... e.g. you can't really say that a snake game **is a** keyboard event, but you *can* say that it **is a** keyboard event *handler* - thinking about it this way often makes design a lot clearer).

Comment: Okey, thank you so much ! Could I ask you for glance to my actually code on github without inheritance ? :P [link](https://github.com/LKlemens/snakeGame) Can be , or go to try shift some variables and methods to other classes,files ?

Comment: @Klemens It is probably better to ask that at http://codereview.stackexchange.com, once your code is working. You'll get input from more people there too. Take a look at some of the successful existing questions there first to get a good idea of how to compose your post there.